# auth() and attempt() helper function are not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

This is my Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware(['guest']);
    }
    public function login(){
        return view('login.login');
    }
    public function logindetails(Request $request){
        request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
           return back()->with('status','Invalid login details');
        }

        return redirect('home');
    }                                                     
}
```

This is my login.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
@if(session('status'))
<article style="color:red;">{{ session('status') }}</article><br>
@endif
<form method="post" action="\logindetails">
@csrf
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" @error('email') style="border-color:red;" @enderror value="{{ old('email') }}"><br>
@error('email') {{$message}} <br> @enderror 
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" @error('password') style="border-color:red;" @enderror><br>
@error('password') {{$message}} <br> @enderror
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LogoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/home',[AdminController::class,'index']);
Route::get('/add',[AdminController::class,'add'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/addpost',[AdminController::class,'addpost']);
Route::get('/edit/{post}',[AdminController::class,'edit']);
Route::post('/editpost/{post}',[AdminController::class,'editpost']);
Route::get('/delete/{post}',[AdminController::class,'deletepost']);
Route::post('/logout',[LogoutController::class,'logout']);
Route::get('/login',[LoginController::class,'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('/logindetails',[LoginController::class,'logindetails']);
Route::get('/register',[RegisterController::class,'register']);
Route::post('/registerdetails',[RegisterController::class,'registerdetails']);
```

```
In registering users, it successfully put in the database.

In logging in, it will always say Invalid login details, 

I guess !auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password')) is not working

I'm wondering what could be the error 

I've also used !Auth::attempt and it also did not work
```

Comment: make sure you have used use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; on the top of LoginController.

Comment: I used Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth for !Auth::attempt but it did not worked, do I need to import that also to use auth() helper function?

Comment: set APP_DEBUG=True in .env file and if you are using helper auth() method there is no need to use Auth Facades; check the error on Developer console.

Comment: APP_DEBUG is already true

Comment: workbench.desktop.main.js:2693 [[object Object]]$(issue-opened)  Nothing to sort.
workbench.desktop.main.js:2693 Error: $(issue-opened)  Nothing to sort.
 at Resolver.sortImports (c:\Users\ADMIN\.vscode\extensions\mehedidracula.php-namespace-resolver-1.1.8\src\Resolver.js:440:19)
 at Resolver.insert (c:\Users\ADMIN\.vscode\extensions\mehedidracula.php-namespace-resolver-1.1.8\src\Resolver.js:250:18)
 at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: Are you using laravel/ui --auth? and on which version of laravel-framework you are currently working?

Comment: Try adding `Log::info($request->only('email','password'));` above your auth line, then check your log in `storage/logs` to see if the data looks correct to you.

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.38

Comment: @aynber where is the storage/logs

Comment: Storage is in your project root directory

Comment: I don't know laravel/ui --auth @ManishJ I think I'm not using it

Comment: @aynber the data in the storage is correct

Comment: check the request log or simply `dd($request->all())` and make sure _token, email, password not empty or  Log::info($request->only('email','password')); and if you are mac or ubuntu user  simply type `$ tail -f ./storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: One more thing you can try is open up your artisan console `php artisan tinker`, and do `Auth::validate(['email' => 'theemailyoure@test.com', 'password' => 'your password']);` and see if it works. If it doesn't, then you need to reset the password.

Comment: I did dd() and Log::info($request->only('email','password')); all are correct

Comment: then make sure to check validations are passed.

Comment: its just required and email   --> 'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'

Comment: I have the answer: its because I have two tables in the database specifically users and registration with email and password as columns so its duplicate, so I deleted registration table and stores in new users in users table

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer: its because I have two tables in the database specifically users and registration with email and password as columns so its duplicate, so I deleted registration table and stores in new users in users table

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).